# Making a graph with a restricted point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to represent a function f(x)=5x/2 with a "hole" in it at (2,5). So far I've tried to do the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-6,xmax=6,
    ymin=-4,ymax=12,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style=<->,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[no marks,black]{(5/2)*x)};
    \draw[d](2,5)circle(1mm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to tackle this. Please help! Thank you.

Here's an example of what it should kind of look like (minus the desmos formatting):

[image: Here lies a graph of 5x/2 with a hole at x=2. Made in desmos.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the command `\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(2,5)};`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*},
             holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
             compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-6,xmax=6,
    ymin=-4,ymax=12,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style=<->,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[no marks,black]{(5/2)*x)};
    \addplot[holdot] coordinates{(2,5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice.  Now suppose you wanted to add the plot y=5 and for that to go through the circle.

Answer (score 2):

You could just draw the circle in the `axis cs` coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-6,xmax=6,
    ymin=-4,ymax=12,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style=<->,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[no marks,black]{(5/2)*x)};
    \draw[fill=white](axis cs:2,5)circle(1mm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]